# Compares two strings lexicographically using charAt() and without using compareTo() method

Tags: java

if the first string is lexicographically greater than the second string it should return 1,if equal return 0,else -1.It is return 1,-1,0 correctly for some cases,but for this str1 and str2 the return is coming out to be the opposite of the desired output.

```
public class StringCompare {

    static String testcase1 = "helloworld";
    static String testcase2 = "hellojavaworld";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringCompare testInstance = new StringCompare();
        int result = testInstance.newCompare(testcase1, testcase2);
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
    }

    // write your code here
    public int newCompare(String str1, String str2) {

        int l1 = str1.length();
        int l2 = str2.length();
        int max = 0;
        if (l1 <= l2) {
            max = l1;
        }
        else
            max = l2;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            char ch1 = str1.charAt(i);
            char ch2 = str2.charAt(i);

            if (str2.charAt(i) > str1.charAt(i)) {
                return - 1;
            }

            if (str1.charAt(i) > str2.charAt(i)) {
                return 1;

            }
            if (l1 == l2) {
                if (ch1 == ch2) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == max) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        }
        if (l1 == l2) return 0;
        if (l1 > l2)
            return 1;
        else
            return - 1;

    }

}
```

Comment: Indentation....

Comment: i did ctrl+k before submitting...

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: It would be good if you can point what cales are giving incorrect output.

Comment: 'w' is greater than 'j' thus your method will return 1 for 'helloworld' and 'hellojavaworld' why do you think it is not working ? You also can remove the code that starts from if(l1 == l2) till the end of the for loop.

Comment: the problem occurs when we compare strings of unequal length.The output is correct for every strings of equal length

Comment: The code you have given in your question is right regarding the lexicographical order; it seems that your definition of “desired output” does not match. `hello < hi` because `e < i`. In other words, comparing `hello` and `hi` gives the same result as comparing `he` and `hi`. And that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified answer

```
public class TestStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(compare("Mike", "Mike"));    // returns 0
        System.out.println(compare("Mikee", "Mike"));   // returns 1
        System.out.println(compare("Mike", "Mikee"));   // returns -1
    }

    public static int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);

            if (c1 > c2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (c2 > c1) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (s2.length() > s1.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (s1.length() > s2.length()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I used a loop, with the stopping condition as the length of the shortest word. If the words are equal after the length of the shortest word, then the longer word is automatically larger. That's what the if statement at the bottom is for.

Comment: System.out.println(compare("aabzzzzzzzz", "b")); //returns -1

Comment: that's how it supposed to work. That's what the compareTo mehtod would return, a negative, meaning b is larger than aabzzzzz. compareTo will compare until the characters don't match, then will return positive or negative. It wont compare the remaining letters

Comment: Try `System.out.println("aabzzzzzzzz".compareTo("b"));`. It returns -1

Comment: yes that is what i am telling according to lexicographical comparison the code is correct but the op wants some other output because the logic of op is correct(other than indentation and he could have made it smaller) and the output which he is getting is correct, but maybe he is wanting something else and thinking that his desired output is what would be lexicographical comparison.

Comment: @Apan, I agree, OP should explain the logic that makes him think aabbzzzzz is greater than b. Then maybe he could get a better answer to what He's looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
public class StringCompare {
    static String testcase1 = "helloworld";
    static String testcase2 = "hellojavaworld";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringCompare testInstance = new StringCompare();
        int result = testInstance.newCompare(testcase1,testcase2);
        System.out.println("Result : "+result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public int newCompare(String str1, String str2){
        int l1=str1.length();
        int l2=str2.length();
        int max=0;
        if(l1<=l2)
        {
            max =l1;
        }
        else
        max=l2;
        int count=0;


        for (int i =0;i<max;i++) {
            char ch1=str1.charAt(i);
            char ch2=str2.charAt(i);

            if(str2.charAt(i)>str1.charAt(i))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if(str1.charAt(i)>str2.charAt(i))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if(l1==l2)
        {
            return 0;
        }else if (l1 < l2){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Your answer is just a copy of the question’s code. If you think you fixed something you should explain what and why.

Comment: It isn't a copy. I remove the last if inside the for.
First we compare the strings asking for each of the characters if they are equals. the loop is only done to the length of the shorter string. then if the two strings are the same length as that implies that the string are the same, but I return -1 or 1 in function that is the longest string.

Comment: You just explained the code of the question in your comment. You did *not* explain why you removed a piece of code and why that ought to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case where **String testcase1 = "helloworld" and String testcase2= "hellojavaworld"**
your **for** loop will run from char 'h' to char 'o'(i=0 to i=4) and none of the if conditions inside your **for** loop will be satisfied and as soon as i gets incremented to 5

```
 //str1.charAt(i)='w' and str2.charAt(i)=j
 if(str1.charAt(i)>str2.charAt(i))   //w(ASCII=119) > j(ASCII=106)
 {
        return 1;                    //return 1 and control return to the calling function

  }
```

So **result=1**. Or in short your code is working properly. 
You can specify what you want the output to be.

Comment: Returning a result based on the first non matching character is exactly what lexicographical comparison is about. I would really like to hear about your alternative…

Comment: the first non-matching character is what is needed,because then only comparison can be done

Comment: @Holger yes that is what i am telling that this program is working correctly, maybe the op wants some other output, because its correct according to **"lexicographical comparison"** point of view

Comment: @user3057435 for str1="hello" and str2="hi" it is returning -1 which is true according to lexicographical comparison

Comment: “what i am telling that this program is working correctly” If you are telling that you should write that into your answer.